# What is wrong in this mysql function ?

Tags: mysql

when i run this function

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alege()
    BEGIN
        declare v_prenumeNou VARCHAR(15);
        declare v_numeRandom INTEGER(10);
        declare v_prenumeRandom INTEGER(10);
        declare v_idCutremurRandom INTEGER(10);

        set v_numeRandom = 1 + CEIL ( RAND() * 50 );
        set v_prenumeRandom = 1 + CEIL ( RAND() * 50 );
        set v_idCutremurRandom = 1 + CEIL ( RAND() * 50 );

        select prenume into v_prenumeNou from (SELECT prenume, rownum as v_rn from voluntari) where v_rn=v_prenumeRandom;
        select nume into v_numeNou from (SELECT nume, rownum as v_rn from voluntari) where v_rn=v_numeRandom;

        v_idPersoanaNou := v_idPersoanaNou + 1;

        INSERT INTO voluntari (IDCUTREMUR, IDPERSOANA, NUME, PRENUME) 
        VALUES (CONCAT('C',IFNULL(v_idCutremurRandom, '')), CONCAT('V',IFNULL(v_idPersoanaNou, '')) , v_numeNou, v_prenumeNou);
END;
```

i have this error

> [Err] 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this, just changed the alias of the from clauses (every deribed table must have an alias):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alege()
    BEGIN
        declare v_prenumeNou VARCHAR(15);
        declare v_numeRandom INTEGER(10);
        declare v_prenumeRandom INTEGER(10);
        declare v_idCutremurRandom INTEGER(10);

        set v_numeRandom = 1 + CEIL ( RAND() * 50 );
        set v_prenumeRandom = 1 + CEIL ( RAND() * 50 );
        set v_idCutremurRandom = 1 + CEIL ( RAND() * 50 );

        select prenume into v_prenumeNou from (SELECT prenume, rownum as v_rn from voluntari) AS A where v_rn=v_prenumeRandom;
        select nume into v_numeNou from (SELECT nume, rownum as v_rn from voluntari) AS B where v_rn=v_numeRandom;

        v_idPersoanaNou := v_idPersoanaNou + 1;

        INSERT INTO voluntari (IDCUTREMUR, IDPERSOANA, NUME, PRENUME) 
        VALUES (CONCAT('C',IFNULL(v_idCutremurRandom, '')), CONCAT('V',IFNULL(v_idPersoanaNou, '')) , v_numeNou, v_prenumeNou);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add an alias to each subquery in your `select into` statements:

```
select prenume 
into v_prenumeNou 
from (SELECT prenume, rownum as v_rn 
      from voluntari) t1  <-----------
where v_rn=v_prenumeRandom;

select nume 
into v_numeNou 
from (SELECT nume, rownum as v_rn 
      from voluntari) t1 <------------
where v_rn=v_numeRandom;
```